# GEE 'featureCollection.union()' keeps failing

Tags: google-earth-engine

I need to perform a union on two separate feature collections (one of species ranges, one of protected areas), which are unavoidably large and complex. My understanding is that this is done using `featureCollection.union()`. It repeatedly fails. See reproducible example for the Atlantic puffin:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Frasenior%2Fpublic%3Apuffin_problem

```js
// Puffin range
var puffinRange = ee.FeatureCollection('users/rasenior/temp/puffin');
Map.addLayer(puffinRange,{color:'blue'},'original');

// Are there different kinds of range polygon?
var rangeTypes = puffinRange.aggregate_array('seasonal').distinct();
print(rangeTypes); // Yes: breeding & non-breeding

// Union of range
var puffinUnion = ee.Feature(puffinRange.union().first());

// Range bounding box
var bbox = puffinUnion.bounds();

// Import PA polygons
var wdpaColl = ee.FeatureCollection('WCMC/WDPA/current/polygons')
  // Filter bounds to species range
  .filterBounds(bbox.geometry())
  // Filter status
  .filter(ee.Filter.inList('STATUS', ['Designated', 'Proposed']))
  // Exlude UNESCO Man and Biosphere reserves because these include 
  // buffer and transition areas which do not meet the IUCN definition of protected areas.
  .filter(ee.Filter.neq('DESIG_ENG', 'UNESCO-MAB Biosphere Reserve'))
  // Exclude 100% marine reserves
  .filter(ee.Filter.neq('MARINE', '2'));

// Union of range
var wdpa = ee.Feature(wdpaColl.union().first());

// Range overlap with all PAs
var rangePA = puffinUnion.intersection(wdpa).area().floor();

// Export the results
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: ee.FeatureCollection(ee.Feature(null, {'rangePA':rangePA})),
  description: 'puffinPA',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```

The union of the species' range cannot be plotted, and exporting the task results in `Execution failed; out of memory.`. Is there anything I can do to make this run? I've tried simplifying the features by 1 km (with cylindrical equal area projection), but so far that has not worked either. Perhaps I have to work with image collections instead?

**EDIT:** The ultimate goal is to calculate the area of overlap between species ranges and Protected Areas. To do this accurately, both feature collections need to be flattened, plus `intersection()` only works on a feature.

Comment: It will help if you describe what you want to *do* with the union. Do you purely want to export it, or do you have further processing in mind? If export, you say you tried simplifying the features, but how much simplification is acceptable in the output? [Edit]ing your question to give more detail about your requirements will help people think of answers.

Comment: Originally I gave more detail, and my question kept being closed as off topic! I want to calculate the area of overlap between the two feature collections (species' ranges and Protected Areas). My understanding (which could be wrong...) is that the feature collections must be flattened before doing this, to calculate area of overlap correctly.

Comment: Thanks. For best answers and attention you should [edit] your question to include that information — not just leave a comment. There's nothing wrong with explaining what your goal is; I can't see your previous attempts (I assume you deleted them) but probably the problem was not _also_ including the code. I've got an idea to try out but your dataset `users/rasenior/temp/puffin` isn't public so I can't run your script — could you fix that?

Comment: Ok, thanks! I'll edit the question. (I did also include the code originally, although it was just a link to the GEE script so maybe wasn't clear enough). Apologies - I'll make the dataset public now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental problems here are that

- WDPA is a large collection of complex polygons.
- Computing unions gets more expensive as geometry gets more complex.
- Any single `Geometry` value in Earth Engine must fit in memory (whereas a feature collection can often be processed one item at a time).

The first thing that came to mind for a way to simplify this operation is that if one of the feature collections involved contained only non-overlapping polygons, then it would be possible to `map` over that collection and compute the area of each feature's intersection with the other collection. However, neither of the collections in your case meets that criterion.

My next idea is to do the entire computation in image space: that is, *paint* the features into images, and count the overlapping pixels in the images. The advantage of this computation strategy is that it need only consider the geometry of each feature (as it intersects with a region of pixels being computed) in isolation — not to compute any geometric unions or intersections.

```js
// Puffin range
var puffinRange = ee.FeatureCollection('users/rasenior/temp/puffin');
Map.addLayer(puffinRange,{color:'blue'},'original', false);

// Range bounding box
var bbox = ee.Feature(puffinRange.union().first()).bounds().geometry();
print(bbox, bbox.area(ee.ErrorMargin(2000, 'meters')));

// Import PA polygons
var wdpaColl = ee.FeatureCollection('WCMC/WDPA/current/polygons')
  // Filter bounds to species range
  .filterBounds(bbox.geometry())
  // Filter status
  .filter(ee.Filter.inList('STATUS', ['Designated', 'Proposed']))
  // Exlude UNESCO Man and Biosphere reserves because these include 
  // buffer and transition areas which do not meet the IUCN definition of protected areas.
  .filter(ee.Filter.neq('DESIG_ENG', 'UNESCO-MAB Biosphere Reserve'))
  // Exclude 100% marine reserves
  .filter(ee.Filter.neq('MARINE', '2'));

// Set up images

var protectedAreaImage = ee.Image.constant(0).paint(wdpaColl, 1);
var puffinRangeImage = ee.Image.constant(0).paint(puffinRange, 1);

// Boolean operation: resulting image is 1 where inputs are 1.
var protectedPuffinRanges = protectedAreaImage.and(puffinRangeImage);

// Display images

Map.addLayer(protectedAreaImage.selfMask(), {palette: ['green']}, 'Protected Areas');
Map.addLayer(puffinRangeImage.selfMask(), {palette: ['blue']}, 'Puffin Ranges');
Map.addLayer(protectedPuffinRanges.selfMask(), {palette: ['#00FFFF']}, 'Intersection');

// Compute area

// We must multiply by the area of pixels to get a value that's a geometric area
// rather than a pixel count.
var rangePA = protectedPuffinRanges.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea()).reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  geometry: bbox,
  crs: /* TODO: something needs to go here */,
  scale: 1000,  // Sampling resolution in meters at the projection's origin
});

// Export the results
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: ee.FeatureCollection(ee.Feature(null, {'rangePA':rangePA})),
  description: 'puffinPA',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```

There's one remaining missing piece, without which this won't work: you need to specify a `crs` (projection) in the `reduceRegion` — this is the projection in which the images are computed, or in other words the grid with which the geometries are sampled. This affects the accuracy of the result, so ideally you want a projection which is reasonably “undistorted” over the entire region, but your region is very large in longitude and latitude, and I'm not aware of what would be best for this particular situation. it might also depend on which areas you care about the most accuracy in.